# How can php code wrapped in if(false) produce an error?

Tags: php, cakephp, apache2.2

I have a situation where code that is wrapped in `if(false) { /* code here */ }` stops a page from loading when it is uncommented. Browser says "the server reset the connection". The environment is:

- CakePHP: 2.5.2
- PHP: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
- Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Any pointers where even to start looking for the reason this happens are welcome!

Edit: the actual code

```
// code above

 exit();
 if(false) {
 /*
    foreach($all_item_types as $ait) {
    $id = $ait['ItemType']['id'];
    $ItemSubtypeVersionView->find('first', array('conditions' => array('item_type_id'=>$id)));
    if(empty($ItemSubtypeVersionView->find('first', array('conditions' => array('item_type_id'=>$id))))) {
        $empty_file_types[$id]= array('n'=>$ait['ItemType']['name']); 
    }
  }
  */
}

// code below
```

Comment: What's the code in there? It's still going to be interpreted.

Comment: Probably a parse error (missing/extra paren, semicolon, closing quote, etc.) If you paste your code we'll probably see it right away.

Comment: `if(false) {` is never coming true. https://3v4l.org/LiYaH

Comment: @CharlotteDunois It's weird that it's even available. What could someone possibly do with a statement that will never come true?

Comment: @jessica That's something you need to ask those who write statements like that.

Comment: I edited in the code in question

Comment: You may want to look into the web server's error log.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I would assume that you're also curious.

Comment: Why do you have a statement that never comes true? What's even the point in writing it?

Comment: false never be true, true never be false, but if false cannot be true, what will false be?? ..lol..

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I can't access the error log on that server and on my local machine it doesn't happen.

Comment: exit() does exactly that and stop executing anything after that point.

Comment: @blues Then you need to ask the server admin to give you the logs.

Comment: @jessica the false is just a placeholder for a condition that is not yet written. and it illustrates here that the code breaks the app even if it is never executed

Comment: @smozgur `exit` does not reset the connection.

Comment: Server resets the connection usually only happens when you have an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP < 5.5, `empty()` can only accept a variable as its parameter. This minor refactor will make your code a little cleaner anyways:

```
if (false) {
    foreach ($all_item_types as $ait) {
        $id = $ait['ItemType']['id'];
        $result = $ItemSubtypeVersionView->find('first', array('conditions' => array('item_type_id' => $id)));
        if (empty($result)) {
            $empty_file_types[$id]= array('n' => $ait['ItemType']['name']); 
        }
    }
}
```